# cannot resolve symbol OnClickListener while making a button to navigate in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to make a simple button that switches between two activites but I'm having several problems.

My code for the entire mainactivity is as follows:

```
 package com.example.project.arithmeticalarm;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

Button newAlarm= (Button)findViewById(R.id.newAlarm);
newAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener);{
    public void onClick(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateAlarm.class));
    }
});
```

}

Everything except the button text at the end was created by default so I havent touched that, but afaik this should be working. The problems I'm having specifically are that I'm getting a "cannot resolve symbol OnClickListener" error, and also a "cannot resolve symbol v", as well as various squiggly red lines around the v and on the final closing bracket.

Please help this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Move your button related code in `onCreate(...)` and also do `newAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener);{`

Comment: That fixes the setOnClickListener problem but I've still got errors around the View v and with the final ), as well as with the ; in (new onClickListener);{

Comment: read my above comment carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Write

```
Button newAlarm= (Button)findViewById(R.id.newAlarm);
newAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateAlarm.class));
    }
});
```

inside method such as in `onCreate` instead of class,because you must initialise view in methods.

Comment: That fixes the setOnClickListener problem but I've still got errors around the View v and with the final ), as well as with the ; in (new onClickListener);{

Comment: Bacause you add `(new OnClickListener);{` extra semicolon.And also override onClick method,use edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `OnClickListener` implementation as following;

```
Button newAlarm= (Button)findViewById(R.id.newAlarm);
newAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateAlarm.class));
    }
});
```

Also do this in `onCreate`.

and it should be working like a charm.